# Duda sobre añadir objetos a ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola tengo dos clases en java:
En una clase tengo un atributo de tipo ArrayList y en la otra clase igual, mi duda es como consigo hacer para eliminar un objeto de un ArrayList de una clase y meterlo en el ArrayList de la otra clase sin hacer los atributos publicos.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], es muy importante que leas [ask], [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional agrega el codigo que llevas hasta el momento.

Comment: ¿las clases se conocen entre si?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un método para agregar los objetos en cada clase y, en una de ellas, hacer un método para *intercambiar* un objeto de una instancia de esa clase a una instancia de la otra, que a su vez, haga uso del método agregar que ya habías creado.

En el ejemplo siguiente ambas clases tienen un método `agregarItem` y la segunda clase tiene además el método `trasladarItem`, que realiza esa función.

```
public class ArrListSO {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClaseLista1 lista1 = new ClaseLista1();
    ClaseLista2 lista2 = new ClaseLista2();

    lista1.agregarItem("uno");
    lista1.agregarItem("dos");
    lista1.agregarItem("tres");
    lista1.agregarItem("cuatro");
    lista2.agregarItem("cinco");
    lista2.agregarItem("seis");
    lista2.agregarItem("siete");
    lista2.agregarItem("ocho");
    lista2.trasladarItem(0, lista1);
    lista1.imprimir();
    lista2.imprimir();
  }
}

class ClaseLista1 {
  ArrayList<String> lista;

  public ClaseLista1 () {
    lista = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public void agregarItem(String valor) {
    lista.add(valor);
  }

  public void imprimir() {
    System.out.println(lista.toString());
  }
}

class ClaseLista2 {
  ArrayList<String> lista;

  public ClaseLista2 () {
    lista = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public void agregarItem(String valor) {
    lista.add(valor);
  }

  public void trasladarItem(int index, ClaseLista1 destino) {
    String valor = lista.remove(index);
    destino.agregarItem(valor);
  }

  public void imprimir() {
    System.out.println(lista.toString());
  }
}
```

La salida que esto produce es:

```
run:
[uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco]
[seis, siete, ocho]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```